# Core Text page break

Tags: iphone, ios, core-text

How can I apply a manual page break in an NSAtrributedString?

For example I would like to have a page break after the end of a chapter.

Comment: http://lists.apple.com/archives/Cocoa-dev/2010/Dec/msg00347.html

Answer (score 0):

Use `\n` in your string to start a new line.